# numpy vectorize max over segments of array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

How can I get rid of the python for loop?  t is not uniformly spaced in general (just in the simple example).  Solutions using pandas are also fine.

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
t = np.arange(n)
y = np.arange(n)
edges = np.array([2., 5.5, 19, 30, 50, 72, 98])

indices = np.searchsorted(t, edges)

maxes = np.zeros(len(edges)-1)
for i in range(len(edges)-1):
    maxes[i] = np.max(y[indices[i]:indices[i+1]])

print(maxes)
```

Update:
I think [reduceat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html#numpy.ufunc.reduceat) might do it but I don't understand the syntax.

Comment: FYI: You can simplify `indices = np.searchsorted(t, edges)` to `indices = np.ceil(edges).astype(int)`.  That's much more efficient, and you don't need `t`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for the suggestion.  In the actual use case t is a non-uniformly spaced float array so I think searchsorted is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reduceat does the job nicely.  I didn't know about that functionality 30 minutes ago.

```
maxes = np.maximum.reduceat(y, indices)[:-1]
```